ZIO doesn't allow to test effect with retry Schedule.exponential
The test just hangs after first repeat
  test("test retry exponential") {
    for {
      _ <- TestClock.adjust(10.milliseconds)
      res <- ZIO.fail("fail").retry(Schedule.exponential(10.milliseconds) && 
         Schedule.recurs(3).tapOutput(o => ZIO.logInfo(s"retrying $o")))
    } yield assertTrue(res == null)
}

It works when I use only Schedule.recurs

I am not sure how exactly to do this (this might help), but I believe the problem is that you want to adjust the clock between retries, not before the fiber is even started like you are doing.

what version of ZIO are you running? What exactly is the question?

TestClock doesn't advance time unless you tell it to. Here is the documentation on how to advance time in your tests.
Schedule.recurs doesn't have a time component. It's immediately ready to recur for how many times you requested. Keep in mind that it recurs 3 times after the initial effect. It probably doesn't matter for your exponential back-off strategy, but in other scenarios it might be important.
The intersection combiner works with the same principles as in a boolean expression. If both schedules are ready to run again, the combined schedule is ready to run. If either left or right schedule is not ready, then the combined one is also not ready. Since your test currently doesn't advance the time, 10 milliseconds will never have passed after the effect failed the first time, so that schedule will just never be ready to run again. Schedule.recurs on the other hand will always be ready to run, until the counter reaches 3. It won't actually advance the counter until the combined schedule is ready to advance though.
As a side note, this assertion:
test("should fail") {
    for {
        res <- ZIO.fail("BOOM!")
    } yield ??? // assert that effect failed
}

...is better expressed like this:
test("should fail") {
    for {
        exit <- ZIO.fail("BOOM!").exit
    } yield assert(exit)(Assertion.fails(Assertion.equalTo("BOOM!"))
}

In order to test failures, you need to call the exit method on the effect. This gives you an Exit, which is sort of like an Either with a success or a failure value, which you can inspect and assert on in your test.
The assert method takes a value in the first parameter list and an Assertion[T] in the second parameter list, where T is the type of the first parameter. As you can see, you can compose these Assertions to make more precise ones. Assertion.fails takes a new Assertion[T] where T is now the value the effect failed with, which is string in our case and perhaps Throwable in another test case.
Sometimes we don't want to assert that every single detail is correct, so there are assertions like Assertion.anything. Assertion.fails(Assertion.anything) may be enough for your particular case. There is also assertCompletes which is a more descriptive alternative to dummy assertions like assert true == true. All it does is to make sure the test didn't fail along the way.
Read more here.

The correct way to test that is to run the effect that is dependent on test clock in a separate fiber to be able to adjust the clock in the main fiber. There is an example in docs. Also, if you only adjust the test clock 10 milliseconds, the code will only retry once. Your code could look along the lines of:
test("test retry exponential") {
  for {
    fiber <- ZIO.fail("fail").retry(Schedule.exponential(10.milliseconds) && 
      Schedule.recurs(3).tapOutput(o => ZIO.logInfo(s"retrying $o"))).fork
    _ <- TestClock.adjust(100.milliseconds)
    res <- fiber.join.exit
  } yield assertTrue(res.isFailure)
}


ZIO.fail("fail").retry(Schedule.exponential(10.milliseconds) &&        Schedule.recurs(3) just illustrates my effect which should return fail only if all 4 attempts are fail.
Meanehile in you approach I receive fail if first attempt will be failed

Is it necessary to test on a separate fiber? Outside of the test setting, both fibers would share the same clock from the environment, right?

@AlexanderWiklund yes, they share the same clock, but the test clock needs to be adjusted (unless you use TestAspect.withLiveClock) after the first failed attempt of the failing effect, so unless you put the failing effect on its own fiber, it will just sit there after first failure waiting for the clock to advance to retry according to exponential schedule and the test will never get to evaluating the clock adjustment. Did I explain this clearly enough?

@IvanK. weird, it worked correctly for me. Which brings us back to my comment on your question: which ZIO version are you using?

Oh your're completely right. I completely overlooked that.
